# Excel 2013 match values in two workbooks and merge one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge

I'm running Excel 2013 and I have two spreadsheets open. The first, sheet1, has two columns and 7k rows the columns are:

```
A                      B

ID                Description

58749651         a bunch of text
```

The second, sheet2, has 24 columns and 26,000 rows. Column "A" is the
same as in the first sheet - title "ID" and the values are numbers. There
is no "description" column in sheet2 - which is my question.

How can I create a description column on sheet 2 (it would be column "U") and
populate it with the description from sheet 1 where the ID values match?

There's probably 1500 or so ID's on sheet1 that are also on sheet2 and I need
to merge just the description from sheet1 into the appropriate row on sheet2.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this or where I can find the information?
Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Hi Rob! Welcome to Super User. Are both the sheets (sheet1 and sheet2) in the same excel file (also called workbook)?

Comment: Hi Prasanna, thanks! No, they are two separate workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a job for VLOOKUP

```
U1:  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[Book2]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$7000,2,FALSE),"")
```

Change Book2 to reflect the proper workbook name where your first list is stored.

Comment: Hey Ron, the first list, the one with just ID & description fields, is "apps1", the second workbook is "nodesc" …I tried changing "book2" to apps1 and it asked me to save the file? In which workbook should I put the formula - and does "sheet1" need to be renamed? Thanks!

Comment: The `U1:` at the beginning of the formula is the cell address where you should put the formula that refers to `A1`, obviously on the same worksheet since `A1` is not qualified by workbook or worksheet name.  Since you are having problems getting the workbook and worksheet references correct, I would suggest using the `Insert Function` bar and selecting the relevant cells in the relevant workbooks/sheets.  Excel will create the proper references for you.

Comment: Thanks again Ron…again, I know I'm missing something…when I put the formula in U1, in the "nodesc" sheet, change "book2" to "apps1", and hit enter…a dialog box opens titled "Update Values:apps1"…and, when I select "apps1" in the file name field I get an Excel error: "Excel cannot update one or more links in this workbook. To update the links, open all the link source files (click edit links on the data tab). So I get that error but also "apps1" is not the file I want to "update" - I want to update the "nodesc" file by inputting the description column from apps1.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting closer! I switched "book2" with "sheet1" and I the formula placed the column ID in U1…! But when I try to drag the formula down the length of column it just keeps putting the column title - "Description" - in the cells.

Comment: @Rob50 Let's see the actual formula you are using. Copy/paste it; do NOT try to type it in.

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[Sheet1]robapps!$A$1:$B$7000,2,FALSE),"")

Comment: Hey Ron, above is the actual formula - that gives copies over the column name "description"…and when I drag it down a few rows, or even do a fill/down, that is all it populates with…I've been messing with it and made some progress - I can now get to give me an "empty cell" error! ;)

Comment: @Rob50 What is the name of the work**book** with a1:b7000; what is the name of work**sheet**

Comment: That would be the workbook with sheet1 - it's: med_id_nodesc.xlsx

Comment: @Rob50 Then (assuming that workbook is open) you formula should look something like: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[med_id_nodesc]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$7000,2,FALSE),"")`  (If the workbook is closed, the full path name and file suffix would replace the file name.  Excel will do this automatically if/when you close that workbook).

Comment: Ron - I have 40 files that contain the descriptions I need - because the original was 1.2gb, so I split. I thought I'd try this with a different file - on the off chance there were no matches in the first file to actually merge. Now I'm completely lost…it keeps inputting "robapps.xlsx" where I put "med_id_nodesc". Also, whenever I run the formula a dialog box opens saying "cannot find robapps.xlsx"! I think I need to close this down and start over…I'm pretty sure you've given me the info I need - I'm just, in case you didn't notice, completely unfamiliar with Excel!

Comment: @Rob50 It sounds like I don't understand your workbooks and worksheets naming schemes.  As I suggested before, I would recommend selecting U1 on the worksheet where you want to show the Description, then select the formula bar -- that should be showing near the top with a little Fx.  Then type in the formula **BUT**, instead of typing any addresses, select the cell(s) that you want to reference.  So instead of typing in [workbook]worksheet!$A$1:$A$7000  you would select that range on the appropriate worksheet/workbook.  If you do this correctly, Excel should figure out the proper reference.

Comment: Maybe that's where I'm getting confused too…one more try? I now have a workbook - "nodesc.xlsx" - and within that I have two sheets. Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Comment: Sheet1 is the master, so to speak…that is the sheet I need to import the "description" column, from sheet2, into. So I need to match any "id" numbers from column A - in both sheets - and where there is a match, import the description, from column b/sheet2, into the Column U on sheet1.

Comment: @Rob50 I'm sure that's part of it.  In your response to Prasana yesterday, you indicated you had two different workbooks.  If you have only a single workbook, then you would not reference the workbook name, only the worksheet name.  But the process I outlined above, of selecting cell ranges using the function bar, would work anyway.

Comment: Thanks again Ron! I'll try it all in one workbook with just the two sheets ;)